# FPV Angle Mix Mode

Tags: betaflight

I’m curious to know what a good starting camera angle would be on whoops when enabling fpv angle mix mode in BetaFlight. Also if it’s not too much to ask, what would the steps be to put that mode on a switch. Thanks much.

Comment: I am flying with half the angle of the cam. But in the end its personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

The camera angle setting in Betaflight should be set to match the angle of the camera on the quad, which you can measure with a protractor.

If you're asking how much to tilt your camera, beginners should start with a fairly low angle. I suggest around 10 degrees although anywhere from 0 to 20 will be flyable. As you start flying faster you might find that you are looking at a point near the top of the screen, or even that your destination is off the top of the screen. That's when it's time to angle the camera up a bit more, until, on average, you're flying towards the middle of the screen.

For anyone that doesn't know, FPV Angle Mix changes the controls so that roll and yaw are relative to the camera, instead of to the flight controller. If you're a beginner with a 10 degree camera angle, you won't notice any difference.